# How to set datetimepicker date based on slider in angular js

Tags: angularjs, datetimepicker

In my application I need to set the date of datetimepicker based on date range slider.

I am getting the dates from slider, but when I go to set it for datetimepicker it is not settings. The Textfield to display dates remains empty.

While moving slider I have set the date in to datetimepicker ng-model value.

I found something strange that after slider move finish, it does not show the dates in datetimepicker textfield but when I click on textfield it shows.

Here is my datetimepicker:

```
<datetimepicker
        ng-click="setStartDateSlider($index)"
        hour-step="hourStep"
        minute-step="minuteStep"
        ng-model="startFrom[$index]"
        show-meridian="showMeridian"
        date-popup="{{format}}"
        date-options="dateOptions"
        date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)"
        datepicker-append-to-body="false"
        readonly-date="false"
        disabled-date="false"
        hidden-time="true"
        hidden-date="false"
        name="datetimepicker"
        show-spinners="true"
        readonly-time="false"
        date-opened="dateOpened"
        show-button-bar="false"
        placeholder="Start From" >

<!-- Use date-ng-click="open($event, opened)" to override date ng-click -->

</datetimepicker>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's jQuery or bootstrapper plugin, you should definitely run `$digest` manually. On slider change event. When you click your textbox, you're triggering $digest.

Just add:

```
scope.$apply();
```

Right after onChange event.

Comment: U r welcome. Hope all proplems solves that easily. :D